# Creating a Batch Report

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I am trying to create a batch report of multiple invoices using SSRS 2008 R2.

I have created the initial invoice report and have it set up with a parameter; the parameter uses an InvoiceID to populate the data within the invoice report.

I have created another report using lists, inside the list contains the information that was in my original invoice report but using a different parameter (BatchID). The problem I am running into with this is that instead of creating a single invoice for each invoiceID it is creating an invoice for each line item within each invoice. i.e.~ Instead of incorporating multiple items based on the InvoiceID (as the original report did) it is creating a report for each of the items.

What would be the best way of running a batch of these invoices? Am I going about this the wrong way or am I on the right track but missing something?

### Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT i.InvoiceId, i.InvoiceNumber, i.BillTo_Line1, i.BillTo_Line2, i.BillTo_City, i.BillTo_StateOrProvince, i.BillTo_PostalCode, i.CustomerIdName, 
                     i.ce_OutstandingBalance, i.ce_BillToDate, i.ce_BillFromDate, i.TotalAmount, id.ProductIdName, id.ce_customeridName, id.ce_CustomerProductName, 
                     id.InvoiceDetailId, id.BaseAmount, id.PricePerUnit, id.ce_rate
FROM 
                         Invoice AS i RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         InvoiceDetail AS id ON i.InvoiceId = id.InvoiceId
```

[image]
Once I enter the invoiceID I get my report
[image]

My intent is to be able to run the report against multiple invoicesid numbers without having to select the invoice number itself. I have another table that collects the invoiceid's based on a batchid that they are run in.

So far I have attempted to create a subreport with the original report and Create a separate report that uses a list and attempt to group by InvoiceID for each batchid. Though with each of these I have so far been unsuccessful.

I am new to SSRS and have been pouring over documentation from MSDN about SSRS and the different abilities.

Comment: Are you able to give a simplified version of your Dataset, a few sample rows of data, plus your required output?

Comment: @IanPreston I edited to show some more detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this sort of repeating list, it's a matter of understanding how a list/grouping works.

Lists, Tables and Matrixes are all the same underlying object - the Tablix.

A List is a Tablix with one detail row (i.e. one Tablix row for each row in the Dataset), one textbox in that row, and a Rectangle in that textbox. The Rectangle can have various embedded elements like more textboxes and as such provides a repeating free-form item for each row in the Dataset.

You can see this when you create a List in the designer:

[image]

I assume your report query takes a `BatchID` and returns a number of invoices and their invoice details. I've taken some liberties with your data and created a simplified sample Dataset:

[image]

You want the Rectangle to repeat for every `InvoiceNo`. Currently the Row Group has no grouping item - change this to `InvoiceNo` under the Group properties and expand the Rectangle as required.

You can start adding in elements such as textboxes for the Invoice level items, something like:

[image]

Note that the left side of the Tablix has changed from lines to a bracket - this is because a grouping item was added to the Row Group.

This will repeat once for each `InvoiceNo`. Now we want to add the line items - you can do this by dragging a new Table into the Rectangle. Since we have a Row Group in place this table will only display items in that group:

[image]

When run for the sample data, this gives an ugly but functional repeating invoice report:

[image]

This could be tidied up as required, and page groups inserted between Group items in the Group properties as required.

Hopefully this at least gives you a rough idea of how you might go about your task.

Comment: I have something similar to this. I created a list box and inside that list box I have created a few items, encompassed with a rectangle. I have added a grouping for that list based on the InvoiceID. While there can be many different items inside the InvoiceID I am only getting the first item; and I don't have the data to select only the first item...=First(...); it is just the entire item from the data set i.e. [Productname]. Is there something that I am missing? Thanks

Comment: NM I got it, I needed to create a table instead of a matrix within the List. That gave me the ability to get multiple values from the items without any issues. ~Thanks again for your help and pointing me in the right direction.